# Ionic push IO: no device token in 'users' assigned to user

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to work with Ionic push notifications and everything went well untill I had to store the Device token which I recieved. I've been following every step the tutorial gave me so I don't see any wrong code in my project.

This is my register code:

```
// kick off the platform web client
        Ionic.io();
        var push = new Ionic.Push();
        // this will give you a fresh user or the previously saved 'current user'
        var user = Ionic.User.current();

        // if the user doesn't have an id, you'll need to give it one.
        if (!user.id) {
            user.id = Ionic.User.anonymousId();       
        }

        var callback = function (data) {
            console.log('Registered token:', data.token); // is not empty
            console.log(data.token);
            push.addTokenToUser(user);
            user.save();
        }
        push.register(callback);
```

I get the following error:

```
Ionic Push Token: dev tokens cannot be saved to a user as they are a temporary resource: ionic.io.bundle.min.js (2,5965).
```

When I'm trying to execute:

```
push.addTokenToUser(user);
```

My ionic interface looks this way:
[image]

I'm actually expecting my device token to get stored in there. But that isn't the case..

I hope some of you guys have seen this problem before and might be able to help me.

Greetings!

Comment: Did you try `ionic config set dev_push false` in the command line before running your app on your device?

Comment: I've already tried that, but that is not the solution sadly. However when I change it to false, I recieve an error which contains: Uncaught TypeError: PushNotification.init is not a function at ionic.io.bundle.min.js (3,0).

Comment: I fixed this error by installing another phonegap push plugin. But now my problem is that the register.push callback isn't called.

Comment: I have exact same problem

Comment: I stopped working with ionic push, but went to using parse instead. I don't have a solution yet, but I'll keep this post online, so if anyone comes by who knows the answer can post it.

Comment: the push.addTokenToUser is not useful anymore, its deprecated, check the new version that is basically linked to Ionic.Auth

Comment: I have the same problem. I think that's because the user logs-in after the creation of the push token, so the token is sent not linked with the user. How can I fix it? I have the last version of cordova (6.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem until I discovered that I was using an old version of cordova (v.4). Anything below v. 5 does not work properly with Ionic (current Cordova version as of writing is 6.0.0).

`npm update -g cordova`

Everything worked as documented after that.

Answer (score 0):

Put Ionic in production mode, so it use the certificate you uploaded. (But still in dev mode for devices)

$ ionic push --production-mode=n